JavaFX do something after property listener is activated
I have this code that saves TableView's TableColumn width size as preference:
column.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldWidth, newWidth) -> {
            setTablePreference().saveColumnWidthSetting(newWidth.doubleValue(), column.getId().concat(columnWidthSettingsCommons.toString()));
        });

The code works as expected (whenever tableColumn width changes, it's automatically saved), but there's room for improvement. When resizing a tableColumn, this code runs hundreds of times due to the listener behavior, which is to listen for any and every change to tableColumn width.
Based on that, I have been wondering if there's a way to run this code only once, right after the listener stop running.
I thought of using a separate thread, but it creates hundreds of threads which by far is not what I'm trying to accomplish (which is performance):
column.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldWidth, newWidth) -> {
            new Thread(new Task<>() {
                @Override
                protected Object call() {
                    setTablePreference().saveColumnWidthSetting(newWidth.doubleValue(), column.getId().concat(columnWidthSettingsCommons.toString()));
                    return null;
                }
            }).start();
        });

So my question is, is there a way to run a code after the listener has stopped listening for new values?

Also consider java.util.prefs.Preferences, examined here.

Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

You could use a PauseTransition to only save the change if no further changes have happened after some pause. But, as described in the answer below, this is simply not the way to save preferences changes; there is no need at all to save them just because the user changed them.

With Preferences, "Normal termination of the Java Virtual Machine will not result in the loss of pending updates…"

@trashgod can't use this library, how will I assure an user logging in from another computer will have it's preferences there? I had to develop my own solution for that

@SedJ601 I don't see how more MRE than provided would be useful, would you please clarify your comment?

@James_D very good suggestion with PauseTransition, probably it's what I've been looking for. Regarding whether to save column width, actually it's very relevant, in a customer experience perspective. Simple scenario: Someone has an old 13' laptop, turning available screen area a potential problem. Everytime that user loads a tableView, it always have to keep increasing/decreasing table width in order to turn information more 'readable' (potentially leading the user to just give up on the platform). Doing that once would be nice, wouldn't it?!

@James_D that feature will be available in the next version (available by the end of the next week), I invite you to check it!
https://www.jdeploy.com/gh/FelipeAumannRS/Nume

@FARS, you appear to be correct.

You misunderstood me. The question is not whether you need to save the column width. The question is whether you need to save it every time the user changes it. Why not just save it when the user closes the window (or hides the table somehow)?

It’s hard to see how you can complain that the answerer of the question hasn’t fully understood your scenario, and that you don’t need a [mre]. The whole point of an mre is to fully clarify the question.

Following @James_D suggestion, I developed an implementation using PauseTransition:
final PauseTransition columnWidthPropertyPauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5));
        column.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldWidth, newWidth) -> {
            adjustNodePosition(tableView);

            if (columnWidthPropertyPauseTransition.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING)
                columnWidthPropertyPauseTransition.play();
            columnWidthPropertyPauseTransition.setOnFinished(e -> setTablePreference().saveColumnWidthSetting(newWidth.doubleValue(), column.getId().concat(columnWidthSettingsCommons.toString())));
        });


The basic solution is to have points in your application that save the preferences (like application close), and let there request the latest values of the column widths. This actually is the normal control flow, not the reversal of control / dependency injection style you use. You can still decouple the preferences from the TableView.
Sketchy:
public class MyPrefsWriter {
    public final Map<String, Producer<String>> props = new LinkedHashMap<>():
    public void savePrefs() {
        props.forEach((k, v) -> savePreference(k, v.get());
    }
}

public class MyPrefsReader { ... }

// Init:
MyPrefsWriter myPrefs = new MyPrefsWriter();


// GUI constructions:
myPrefs.props.put("columnXWidth", () -> columnX.width.toString());
...

// On exit:
myPrefs.savePrefs();

As from a TableView you can get all widths in one piece of code, that might be better, more compact (saveTableViewToPrefs, loadTableViewFromPrefs).

Thanks for answering, but I really don't get those upvotes. This is just not an acceptable approach based on my scenario: my applications has dozens of tableViews (but the user is able to create thousands of it if needed). Those tableViews are divided by modules (each module working individually, somewhat like an app). Those modules can be closed (in order to let the application free up some memory and cpu), that's why I can't just save preferences while application is closing

Btw, no one mentions it but using Preferences from java.util and writing preferences only when application is closing has a huge draw back: it might not persist the information in scenarios where the application's process is killed, computer is shut down unpredictably, etc

@FARS The general advice of this answer is to save the preferences at certain points in the flow of your application. One such point (given as an example in this answer) is when the application is closed. In your case, another point would be when a "module" is closed. As for the draw back you mention, preferences are not typically considered critical data. But if you want to provide near real-time persistence of a user's preferences, then the delay approach described by James_D is probably best for you.

@Slaw I agree, I'm already developing an implementation based on his approach
